# Firebase cloud function process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG.projectId is undefined

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, environment-variables

From Firebase official docs on cloud functions:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#automatically_populated_environment_variables

[image]

I need to access the `projectId`, so I'm trying:

```
type FirebaseConfigEnv = {
  databaseURL: string,
  storageBucket: string,
  projectId: string
}

export const helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const FIREBASE_CONFIG = process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG as unknown as  FirebaseConfigEnv;
  response.send(`FIREBASE_CONFIG.projectId: ${FIREBASE_CONFIG.projectId}`);
});
```

And I'm getting on the browser the following result:

[image]

Why is the `process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG` object not being properly populated on my runtime environment?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The value of `process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG` is a JSON string. As strings do not have a property called `projectId`, you get `undefined`.

To use it like you expect, you must first parse it as shown at the bottom of the [documentation you linked](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#automatically_populated_environment_variables):

```
const FIREBASE_CONFIG = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG);
const projectId = FIREBASE_CONFIG.projectId;
```

Comment: Great spot Raphael, just take note of the edit on how to properly format your answer with code blocks. Try to stick to the format "Problem" -> "Reference" -> "How to fix" -> "Fixed Code". Be confident in your answer as you were correct and try to leave out "try this" statements as they are better suited for comments.

Comment: OMG i cant believe google used this stupid design decision... as the starter of the question I also assumed that the variable was an object and not a striing for obvious reasons, thanks for the answer